# ASP.net on-line calendar consumed into outlook

Tags: asp.net, web-services, calendar, outlook

I have an on-line calendar of company events that is based in a sql table.

The fields are

Date : Event Name : Event Description : Location

Is there any way of publishing this via say an rss feed via asp-net or a web service for it to be consumed into the outlook calendar.

This would have to update every morning on the subscribers screen every morning.

All I can see is that there is a file .ics (internet calendar) but have no idea how I would get asp net to produce one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/

i suggest you grab version 0.80 of DDay.iCal.